# How to check for session in JSP EL?

Tags: java, jsp, session, el

How do you check if a session exists for the request in EL? I'm trying something like:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.session != null}"> ... </c:if>
```

but it seems like it's never null.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's indeed never `null`. The session is *always* present in JSP EL, **unless** you add

```
<%@page session="false" %>
```

to top of JSP. You could then check for the session as follows (EL 2.2 only!):

```html
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.getSession(false) != null}">
    <p>The session has been created before.</p>
</c:if>
```

I'm not sure what's the concrete functional requirement is. If you'd like to check if the session is new or has already been created, use [`HttpSession#isNew()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#isNew%28%29) instead.

```html
<c:if test="${not pageContext.session['new']}">
    <p>You've already visited this site before.</p>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${pageContext.session['new']}">
    <p>You've just started the session with this request!</p>
</c:if>
```

*(the brace notations for `new` are mandatory because `new` is a reserved literal in Java language)*

Of if you're relying on a *specific* session attribute, such as the logged-in user which is been set as

```
session.setAttribute("user", user);
```

then you should rather be intercepting on that instead:

```html
<c:if test="${not empty user}">
    <p>You're still logged in.</p>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${empty user}">
    <p>You're not logged in!</p>
</c:if>
```

Comment: You're too good, answering a question I didn't even ask. Checking for the user was what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome. Questions which makes no sense in real world code have often a completely different functional requirement behind. Then I often guess for the most common functional requirements which look much like whatever you *really* need to achieve. You would save me (and others) time if you just state that in your future questions ;)

Comment: It's sometimes easy to get caught up in a coding storm and forget to take a step back and realize the approach is wrong altogether. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to works with:

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(sessionScope) > 0}">
```

I wonder if there's a better way, since this requires that I have session attributes (I always do, but it's not really clean)?

Answer (score 1):

In J2EE there will always be a session object when a user visits a site.

What is a Session ?
A session is pretty much what it sounds, when a user makes a page request to the server, the server creates a temporary session to identify that user. So when that same user goes to another page on that site, the server identifies that user. So a session is a small and temporary unique connection between a server and the user enabling it to identify that user across multiple page requests or visits to that site.

So basically if your hitting a page you have a session because your using JSP, which eventually gets converted to servlets.

http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2001062001&page=1